# Find arg of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Find $$Arg \frac{1+z}{1-z}$$.

I transfomed it and I have something like that:
$$Arg\frac{1-x^2-y^2+2iy}{(1-x)^2+y^2}$$

And do not any idea how to find Arg. I tried to calculate it but it's horrible and don't know how to finish it.

Comment: it's a good start to decompose into real and imaginary parts! :) Now use the formulas  in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number , section "polar form"

Comment: Just as tired commented, define $X=\frac{1-x^2-y^2}{(1-x)^2+y^2}$ and $Y=\frac{2y}{(1-x)^2+y^2}$

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this formula. Good to know:)